# including if else clause creates type error

Tags: typescript, redux

Following a tutorial by the creator of Redux, I created a function called configureStore to create the store for my app as you see below. The example where I compile without the if/else clause compiles without error. However, if I use the if/else check (which I need), then it doesn't compile saying

```
index.tsx type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Store<any>'
```

Why does putting the code inside an if/else clause affect the type (and how can I make it compile correctly)?

**configureStore.tsx**  (won't compile -- `index.tsx type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Store<any>'`)

```
export const configureStore = () => {
    const persistedState = loadState();
    let store: Store<any>;
    if ((<any>window).serverSidePersistence != true) {
        store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    } else {
        store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)); 
    }
    return store;
}
```

**configureStore.tsx** (compiles without error)

```
export const configureStore = () => {
    const persistedState = loadState();
    let store: Store<any>;
    store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState,applyMiddleware(thunk));
    return store;
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
 const store: Store<any> = configureStore();
```

Comment: This looks contingent on what `createStore` returns. Can you post its function declaration?

Comment: createStore is a redux library function.  http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer

Comment: also, the actual source https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L39

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on the typescript playground with Redux's .d.ts. What version of TypeScript are you using? What are the types of the variables involved? What happens when you don't give `store` a type?

Comment: it's typescript 2.3. Not giving store a type created a different error.  error TS2322 Type'{store:void; children: Element;}' is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Provider> & REalonly<{children ?: ReactNode;}> &...'

Comment: This looks correct to me (and it at least compiles when I try it in a typescript/react project).  I have found that weird errors like this often get resolved when I wipe out the `node_modules` directory---I think there's currently something wrong with yarn/npm's dependency management that is affecting typescript.  Just a hunch, though.

Comment: try to compile 

     `const persistedState = loadState();`
     `let store: Store<any>;`
     `store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));`
     `return store;`

look like `createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))` has wrong type

Comment: @Vestild I don't see any difference with what you're doing

Comment: can you try `configureStore = (): Store<any> => {`, so be implicit about return type of the function and see if it at least leads you to the issue source, also in your compilable version try the else part

Comment: @Leahcim , does this compiles ?  : export const configureStore = () => {
    const persistedState = loadState();
    let store: Store<any>;
    store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk));
    return store;
}

Comment: Did you miss an import of configureStore in index.tsx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TypeScript 1.6 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html) state:

> TypeScript 1.6 introduces a new `.tsx` file extension. This extension
>   does two things: it enables JSX inside of TypeScript files, and it
>   makes the new as operator the default way to cast (removing any
>   ambiguity between JSX expressions and the TypeScript prefix cast
>   operator). For example:

```
var x = <any> foo;
// is equivalent to:
var x = foo as any;
```

The type cast `<any>window` in the line:

```
if ((<any>window).serverSidePersistence != true) {
```

is thus not interpreted as a cast in a `.tsx` file, but as a jsx element. You should be good to go when using the new type casting syntax:

```
if ((window as any).serverSidePersistence != true) {
```